# Laravel the actual order of rows

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

In Laravel 5.1, Is there a way to know the order of a specific ID in a table. Like say I have a table called articles as follows:

```
ID|Title | Body
----------------,
1 |   x  | y
2 |   x  | y
10|   x  | y
12|   x  | Y  
14|   x  | y
```

In the above table we have article with ID 10 is the third, this means articles from 3 till 9 are deleted. Also article with ID 12 is the fourth and article ID 14 is the fifth. How can I know that Article ID 10, for example, is third in the table?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need that info?

Comment: Does it matter? Long story but sadly I need this functionality

Comment: If you use laravel you may use variable $loop in eny for each for etc.... $loop->index will give you the index of the row starting with 0. Good for numbering table rows. Don't know if this is what you need.

Comment: Yes, it is laravel, could you please submit a simple solution. I don't think it is available at v5.1

Answer (score 0):

For instace:

```
$articles = Article::all();
$counter=1;
foreach($articles as $article) {
    echo $counter.'-'.$article->id;
    echo '</ br>' ;
    $counter++;
}
```

Will result in:

```
1-1
2-2
3-10
4-12
```

.......

Comment: Thanks. but loop->index is only available from Laravel 5.3 while i'm using an older version

Comment: Only if you use good old fashion counter. Initialize bofore loop: $counter=1. Inside the loop do $counter++. Counter will hold the number of rows as you pass through.

Comment: so if I want to know the order of article ID 10, i have to make a call to get all the rows in the DB and then compare each one with ID 10?

Comment: There are some tweaks to get that based on what DB you use. For instance. http://constituteweb.com/how-to-get-the-rownumber-in-laravel-eloquent. I still think you don't need that row number.

Comment: I think it is very very weird of you to keep asking about why I need x functionality

Comment: In 8 years of php/MySQL experience I didn't need to know the row number where an model/object is stored in a DB table. Now you can understand my curiosity. As you can see the row number is dynamic, changes as DB evolves. The only thing that cannot change easily is the ID/key of that row.